# Changed water and fish dying

Tags: fish, diseases

Hi I started up my tropical aquarium about 2 months ago. Changed part of the water a few days ago I might have put to much sausage in it both my angel fish died and now the other 3 are not looking very good.

I just move them into a bowl with part aquarium water & part tap anyway I noticed two of thems tails are gone is that from me or is that something else?

Comment: What do you mean with "put too much sausage in it"? If you think the water is polluted, you'd better do a 50% water change.

Comment: No so sorry I tried to correct that sometimes I think this phone has a mind of its own. I did  change the whole tank and clean the tank with bleach  and boiled rocks just in case of a disease.

Comment: If you use chemicals like bleach be careful - they might be poisonous for your fishes. Before you put them back in the tank you should change the water several times. E. g. 20% a day for a week or so. Do not change the whole water at one time. In a pet store you should be able to find some appropriate medicine for your fishes.

Answer (score 3):

You probably intoxicated the fish with the remains of bleach. The containers usually have a warning label that it's toxic for water organisms. There you go.

[image]

Boiling the decoration if they support it is a good idea. Better is to put them in a saturated salt dissolution (put table salt in boiling water until you see some of it fall to the ground and let it cool down). This will kill eggs of paracites which will survive the boiling.

Cleaning the empty aquarium with warm water is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems like you might have contaminated your tank by using bleach to disinfect it. I recommend going to your local pet store and getting a side tank and some tropical fish solution (like this [one](http://www.tetra-fish.com/products/water-care/easybalance-plus.aspx)).

If your fish are losing their fins, this is usually considered the disease "fin rot". Read this [quick guide](https://www.thesprucepets.com/fin-rot-1378481) on how to avoid this in the future. I believe they do also sell "antibiotics" to cure your fish, but it'd be best to ask the fish expert at the pet shop!

I hope your fish do end up feeling better!

Comment: Thanks for the Quick guide link I think I have a neon with FR